# Enable 'Transfer-Encoding: Chunked' on cloudfront

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

How can I enable `transfer-encoding: chunked`  on my cloudfront CDN?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what specific behavior you are expecting.  `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is already automatically available on all CloudFront distributions... but of course it won't be something that happens unless your origin supports it.  There would be no advantage or purpose that comes to mind, otherwise.